How to successfully migrate a (very) old PostgreSQL database with PostGIS objects to a new version of PostgreSQL and PostGIS
I've been trying to migrate a PostgreSQL database on version 9.0.1 with PostGIS objects to PostgreSQL version 12.9 (both on Linux) and I've been encountering numerous errors. I believe the source version of PostGIS is version 1.5 however when I execute the query SELECT PostGIS_Full_Version(); in the source db I get the following

Error: function postgis_full_version() does not exist

The only reason I suspect it is version 1.5 is because doing a "regular" pg_dump copy (as if there are no PostGIS objects) results in seeing the following error in the log:

ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-1.5": No such file or
directory

The destination PostGIS version is 3.0.3.
In previous migrations from this same source instance I've never had any issues using the available postgis_restore.pl script. One difference with this database is there is a postgis schema, also I have a feeling this database might have been previously migrated from an even older version of PostgreSQL/PostGIS as it has the word _Legacy in the database name.
Common examples of errors seen in the log include:

ERROR:  operator does not exist: geometry postgis.&& geometry
ERROR:  type "postgis.box2d" does not exist
invalid command \N

Also, any table with PostGIS datatypes do not copy over. I perform all the usual steps like adding the PostGIS extension and topology extension. I also tried migrating this database to PostgreSQL 10, but got the same result. So my hunch is maybe I should pg_dump the postgis schema first and then try the postgis_restore.pl script and see if all the tables/schemas copy over? I'm fairly new to PostgreSQL so I am kind of at a loss here. I've also tapped my local Esri expert here and they didn't really know what to say.

More StackOverflow/DBA question but https://stackoverflow.com/a/62198992/749066

I thought so...

When the migration gap is that far, you're better off dumping the data to SQL INSERT statements using WKT for geometry (ST_AsText()).

@Vince - I did try migrating to a PostgreSQL v10.5 instance with PostGIS 2.4.4 installed and encountered the same issues/errors, is that too a big gap?

Apparently. Most software is only certified for upgrade for up to 3-4 releases back. There were nine major releases between 9.0.x and 12.x. 10.5 is still seven releases out.
